# What's the connection between these two categories of games and innocent strategies?

Tags: semantics, ct.category-theory

Lately I've been reading a lot about game semantics and in particular the problem of [PCF's full abstraction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100929304).

I'm trying to understand how the definition from [this](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/harmer-hyland-mellies-categorical-combinatorics.pdf) article relates to the one found in [this](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~gam23/papers/marktoberdorf.ps.gz) notes (section 3.4).

The definition in the notes seem to follow quite closely the original definition used by [Abramsky et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100929304) and [Ong and Hyland](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~urzy/SPFiL/Abramsky-i-inni/hylandong-iandc00.pdf).
The definition of the category $\mathcal{INN}$ in the article is more interesting since it uses some more advanced categorical construct(a distributive law between a comonad and a monad) and makes (even) more obvious the connection with linear logic(namely: models of linear logic are given by an adjunction between a symmetric monoidal closed category and a cartesian category).

However I don't understand exactly how $\mathcal{INN}$ is related to $\mathcal{C}_{ib}$ defined in the notes.

For example, reading the article I don't see any mention of well-bracketing(actually the article doesn't even divide the game moves into question and answers). Is this condition implicit somewhere in the definition they give? If yes how?

One of the authors, Hyland, also wrote one of the "original articles" about PCF's full-abstraction. In that article they put the well-bracketing condition in the definition of legal play and hence it is included in the condition of "innocence". It seems strange that they simply ignore it in the article.

Another thing I wonder: is $\mathcal{INN}$ cpo-enriched? Or, more generally, can we obtain the same(or very similar) full-abstract model of PCF using $\mathcal{INN}$ instead of $\mathcal{C}_{ib}$? Is there some major difference that wont allow this?

---

Note that Hyland et al, in the introduction of the article I linked, state that their "aim is to derive the *original notion of innocent strategy* together with its basic properties from structure on a primitive category $\mathcal{G}$ of games.", which I believe is in favor of the "equivalence" of $\mathcal{INN}$ with the category used to model the semantics of PCF, however they never make an explicit statement about this and the category they define in the article.

---

**Update:**
It just occurred to me that the definition of games and strategies in [the article](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/harmer-hyland-mellies-categorical-combinatorics.pdf) seems to only consider the "well-opened" games(as defined in [the notes](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~gam23/papers/marktoberdorf.ps.gz)), i.e. the games whose plays contain a single initial move at the beginning.

This would make much sense since then we can interpret the games $!?A$ and $?!A$ that arise when defining $\mathcal{INN}$ through the distributive law as generic games(since the $!$ and $?$ "allow backtracking" and hence more than an initial move can happen in a single play).

Does this make any sense?